# Why does raster's cell size change due to rotate and georeference using Georeference toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, georeferencing

I just found out that the cell size of raster change after I rotate or georeference it with Georeference. Is there any explanation why it works that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a regular grid of points aligned with your X and Y axis, and you rotate it, then the distance between your points parallel to the X (or Y) axis will change. This is the same with pixels, because they are resampled as rectangles with their sides parallel to the axis.

As for the georeferencing, it can include a change in scale, so obviously the pixel size might change. This change in scale depends on the projection (some projection will locally preserve the distances, but most don't)

Comment: Your answer explains it well, thank you very much :)